# Can ffmpeg trim the beginning of a video as it's written?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, encoding, mp4

I'm working on an Android app where I want to keep a 30s buffer of video, and at arbitrary times save it. I have a few requirements:

- I want to make sure I don't miss or duplicate any frames. So I think periodically starting and stopping recording won't work
- I found that simultaneously encoding two video streams puts my CPU under a lot of strain, so I want to avoid doing that
- I don't want to store a ring buffer of 30s worth of frames in memory as that'll require too much memory. So I think I need to encode them to a video file on disk as they come in. (though I'm realizing maybe I could write the frames to disk and encode them when I have a 30s buffer I want to keep)

This all leads me to think the best solution would be something like a typical camera app where a video is written to an mp4 file as it's recorded. But to keep the filesize reasonable, I'd like to have the output file continuously trimmed to the last 30s, plus or minus a keyframe interval.

I know that ffmpeg can do that for a video that's not being currently written. But I don't know if something about the format of an mp4 would prevent doing that for a video that is being written. For example, if an mp4 was essentially a series of bitmaps with timestamps, I'd think it's easy for ffmpeg to chop off some number of frames at the beginning while the camera API is writing frames to the end. Is there anything about the mp4 format that makes it too complicated to do that in practice? Or is this a question that depends on the camera API's implementation?